# object scalatest is not a member of package org

Tags: eclipse, scala, sbt, scalatest

I want to write some tests for my toy project in scalatest. As I use `sbt` I installed scalatest via `libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.0.M5" % "test"` in my project root's `build.sbt`. Then I created test class in `src/test/scala`:

```
package parsers

import org.scalatest.FunSuite

class BaseParserSuite extends FunSuite {

    test("test works") {
        val result = 2
        assert(result === 2)
    }
}
```

I run it via `sbt test` and it works. But the annoying thing is that on line 3 with `import org.scalatest.FunSuite` eclipse says:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - object scalatest is not a member of package org
    - object scalatest is not a member of package org
```

The `import` part is taken from [this example](http://www.scalatest.org/getting_started_with_fun_suite). So the general question is: why is it working via sbt and eclipse reports the error? And where is the imported code from `org.scalatest.`? Or it is not physically downloaded to my computer? And as a guess -- should I add something to .classpah eclipse file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use the sbt elcipse plugin. It generates eclipse project definitions from your sbt build definition so all the libraries needed will be on the class path. See https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse#for-the-impatient

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue and resolved by deleting the project (do not click on the delete the actual files checkbox). And then I imported the "preexisting project in workspace".