# Scala - object junit is not a member of package org

Tags: eclipse, scala, junit

I am doing the Scala course from Coursera.

I have a test file containing the following line:

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
```

Here, I get the following error:

```
Multiple markers at this line:
- object junit is not a member of package org
- object junit is not a member of package org
```

My question is similar to this one:
[object scalatest is not a member of package org](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14182963/object-scalatest-is-not-a-member-of-package-org)

I followed the answer by adding to my `build.sbt`:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "4.0.0")
```

However, when I run `eclipse` in the scala console inside the root folder of my project I get:

```
<console>:11: error: not found: value eclipse
       eclipse
```

Comment: you do not run the eclipse task in the scala console, but at the sbt prompt, or directly by calling 'sbt eclipse" on the shell/DOS command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `build.sbt`, you need to add the line above to the `plugins.sbt` file in your project folder. If it does not exist, you should create it.